# Issue with Unicorn Deploy to Heroku - production environment issues only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku, production-environment, unicorn

I'm having problems deploying to Heroku.  Everything works fine on my development machine (I'm using Foreman/Unicorn to run the web worker and background DelayedJob process).  However when I try to run in Production on Heroku, I get strange errors about logger...

```
app error: undefined method `tagged' for #<Logger:0x00000005aee368> (NoMethodError)
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:14:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:132:in `forward'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:241:in `fetch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:181:in `lookup'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:65:in `call!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:50:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.2.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:530:in `process_client'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.2.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:604:in `worker_loop'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.2.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:487:in `spawn_missing_workers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.2.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:137:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.2.0/bin/unicorn:121:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:19:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:19:in `<main>'
```

The confusing part is that it the error trace is all gem code... maybe something wrong with my unicorn / proc file?

Unicorn:

```
worker_processes 3 # amount of unicorn workers to spin up
preload_app true
timeout 30         # restarts workers that hang for 30 seconds

@delayedjob_pid = nil

before_fork do |server, worker|
  @delayedjob_pid ||= spawn("bundle exec rake environment jobs:work QUEUE=immediate")
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Proc:

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
```

I can post whatever else would be useful!!! Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Heroku does not currently get along well with Rails 3.2, and custom logging.

What fixed my issue - comment out the following:

```
 #config.log_tags = [:uuid, :remote_ip]
```

See also
http://broadcastingadam.com/2012/01/rails320_heroku_and_rails_log_stdout

Comment: Glad you solved it. Nothing like stepping through a stack trace of debug code to find out it's a compatibility issue :/

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for your development issues, so this is more of a suggestion than an answer (but it requires a bit more space than an answer).

I've had issues with Heroku and services/gems in the production environment in the past. What I recommend you do is create a staging environment on Heroku and test your code there. However, you should test it in two manners:

- A vanilla staging environment to begin with then...
- Add the heroku services one by one and test your application.

I had an issue with Relic once where everything worked in Dev and Staging, but production didn't work at all. Turned out that version of relic wasn't compatible the the version of Rails for some reason.

Also, with regards to your question, what Heroku stack are you running on? Are you running on the Cedar stack or Bamboo?

Comment: Thanks for the start towards an answer.  I'm on Cedar stack.  My application has been working in the past, so I'm not too sure what exactly changed that broke everything.  The error trace doesn't help either which is why I'm on here!

Comment: P.S. This is in a "clean" production install with Heroku (no services have been activated) - it is my development code ported straight into production